# What are the relationships amongst AWS, Parse, and MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, parse-platform

What are the relationships amongst AWS, Parse, and MongoDB? How do they integrate together? I'm not just looking for the differences. Also, I have looked at high level answers online but seek a more in depth answer please.

My understanding is that Parse and MongoDB are both databases, but why do we need AWS in the mix? If Parse is not specifically a database, then where is the database when I use parse for my iOS apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS definition from Wikipedia,

> AWS offers a suite of cloud computing services that make up an on-demand computing platform.

Parse is a Mobile Backend as a Service provider. You can use their SDK to store data on Parse backend.

MongoDB defination from Wikipedia

> MongoDB (from humongous) is a free and open-source cross-platform document-oriented database. Classified as a NoSQL database, MongoDB avoids the traditional table-based relational database structure in favor of JSON-like documents with dynamic schemas

Comment: @jayswift aws provides infrastructure on cloud, think of it more like your personal system. User can install and configure packages on server. deploy your scripts on aws.

Comment: @jayswift Parse is BaaS, which means you can store or retrieve data on backend. However you need to use their SDK. learn their syntax (which is much more custom). MongoDB is just a database.

Comment: Thank you so much. All this information is very helpful @roshan

Comment: What kind of infrastructure does AWS provide us on the cloud?

Comment: Is it correct to say that parse is a database just like MongoDB?

Comment: @jayswift parse is not just a database, it's BaaS. Parse have its own SDK. These SDK's specify how you can store/access database on parse

Comment: @AWS provides many services on cloud. i think you are using only ec2 instances for now (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud)

Comment: @jayswift please the answer as accepted if it answers your question